# Tensorflow distributed:how let two workers on tow machine

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed

I want to let one worker on "10.222.152.100" and another on "10.222.152.101".
This is worker1.py :

```
worker_1="10.222.152.100:2222"
worker_2="10.222.152.101:2222"
worker_host=[worker_1,worker_2]
cluster_spec=tf.train.clusterSpec({"FirstJob":worker_host})
server=tf.train.Server(cluster_spec,job_name="FirstJob",task_index=0)
server.join()
```

This is worker2.py :

```
worker_1="10.222.152.100:2222"
worker_2="10.222.152.101:2222"
worker_host=[worker_1,worker_2]
cluster_spec=tf.train.clusterSpec({"FirstJob":worker_host})
server=tf.train.Server(cluster_spec,job_name="FirstJob",task_index=1)
server.join()
```

And I want let the loss on worker1 and the train on woeker2,the Client.py is Linear Regression:

```
w=tf.Variable(0.0,name="W")
b=tf.Variable(0.0,name="b")

with tf.devic("job:FirstJob/task:0/"):
    loss=tf.square(Y-tf.mul(X,w)-b)
with tf.devic("job:FirstJob/task:1/"):
    train=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)
with tf.Session(target) as sess:
    init=tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(100):
        for (x,y) in zip (Train_X,Train_Y):
            sess.run(train,feed_dic={X:x,Y:y})
```

my IP is "10.222.152.100",when target="10.222.152.100:2222" ,it prints:

```
Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/job:FirstJob/task:1'
```

when target="10.222.152.101:2222",it prints:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.UnimplementedError
```

Hope your help >>>

Comment: Can you show the code you use to create a  `tf.Session`?

Comment: I'll show all code

Comment: what is a tow machine?